# How to get file size using url, in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, keystonejs

I have some images in url(s). I can get file properties and properties include width and height of image as well. I want to get the size in **bytes**.

I am trying to get size using fs module as shown below, but it is not working with url, though it works with file path in local folder.

```
var stats = fs.statSync(url);
var fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"]
```

Comment: If you're not requesting a local resource, you'll need to use the `http` or `https` modules to make a request for those resources.

Comment: In addition to @zzzzBov keep in mind, that it could be needed to download the whole file to get the filesize, if the server is not correctly configured. Not every server returns the `content-length` in http header. So this is not the best idea, to get a remote file size ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use `request`, or `http`. You can get the file size by sending a `HEAD` request and inspect `content-length` field (**it will not work on every server**):

---

With `curl`:

```
curl -I "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/core.js"
```

You get the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 03 Apr 2018 14:30:16 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 9068
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 04:16:30 GMT
ETag: "5a962d1e-236c"
Expires: Sun, 24 Mar 2019 14:30:16 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=30672000
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
CF-Cache-Status: HIT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15780000; includeSubDomains
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 405c3b6e1911a8db-CDG
```

---

With `request` module :

```
var request = require("request");

request({
    url: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/core.js",
    method: "HEAD"
}, function(err, response, body) {
    console.log(response.headers);
    process.exit(0);
});
```

You get the response:

```
{
  date: 'Tue, 03 Apr 2018 14:29:32 GMT',
  'content-type': 'application/javascript; charset=utf-8',
  'content-length': '9068',
  connection: 'close',
  'last-modified': 'Wed, 28 Feb 2018 04:16:30 GMT',
  etag: '"5a962d1e-236c"',
  expires: 'Sun, 24 Mar 2019 14:29:32 GMT',
  'cache-control': 'public, max-age=30672000',
  'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
  'cf-cache-status': 'HIT',
  'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15780000; includeSubDomains',
  'expect-ct': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
  server: 'cloudflare',
  'cf-ray': '405c3a5cba7a68ba-CDG'
}
```

Comment: Only works if the server is returning `content-length`. Not a secure aproach.

Comment: Yeah it's specified, it depend if he know which server he target

Comment: Isn't your aproach downloading the whole file and not the headers only?! Not completely sure ...

Comment: You might want to use `request.head` so that it doesn't download the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

## file_size_url

Get file size from URL without downloading it.
0 dependencies.

Returns Promise with 'B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB' on success.

```sh
npm i file_size_url
```

```js
import file_size_url from 'file_size_url';

file_size_url("https://server10.mp3quran.net/bader/Rewayat-Hafs-A-n-Assem/001.mp3")
    .then(console.log) // 968.27 KB
    .catch(console.error);
```

OR

```js
import file_size_url from 'file_size_url';

let size = await file_size_url("https://serverjyy10.mp3quran.net/bader/Rewayat-Hafs-A-n-Assem/0001.mp3")
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))

console.log(size) // 968.27 KB
```

Example for lop

```js
let array = [

    'https://server10.mp3quran.net/bader/Rewayat-Hafs-A-n-Assem/001.mp3',
    'https://server10.mp3quran.net/bader/Rewayat-Hafs-A-n-Assem/002.mp3',
    'https://server10.mp3quran.net/bader/Rewayat-Hafs-A-n-Assem/003.mp3',
    'https://server10.mp3quran.net/bader/Rewayat-Hafs-A-n-Assem/055.mp3',
    'https://server10.mp3quran.net/bader/Rewayat-Hafs-A-n-Assem/110.mp3',

]

for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {

    try {

        let fies_size = await file_size_url(array[index])

        if (fies_size.toString().split('.')[0] <= 95 && fies_size.toString().split(' ')[1] === 'MB') {

            console.log(fies_size + ' || <= 95 MB');

        }

        else if (fies_size.toString().split('.')[0] > 95 && fies_size.toString().split(' ')[1] === 'MB') {

            console.log(fies_size + ' || > 95 MB');

        }

        else if (fies_size.toString().split(' ')[1] === 'KB') {

            console.log(fies_size + ' || KB');

        }


    } catch (error) {

        console.log(error);

    }

}


/* output 
968.27 KB || KB
170.58 MB || > 95 MB
95.77 MB || <= 95 MB
12.21 MB || <= 95 MB
711.92 KB || KB
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the image to your ephemeral `/tmp/` directory, then treat it as a regular file.

```js
const request    = require("request"),
      fs         = require("fs"),
      remote_url = "https://example.com/image.jpg",
      path       = '/tmp/media.jpg',
      media      = request(remote_url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));

media.on("finish", () => {
  return fs.statSync(path).size;
});
```